# UITextView Maximum Height

Tags: ios, uitextview

I use a `UITextView` in my app and I set it's frame based on the size of the text. However, if the `UITextView.size.height` is greater than 8192.0, the text just disappears.

Does `UITextView` have a maximum height?

**EDIT**

I appreciate all the answers so far, but I'm already able to set the frame with no problem. The problem is that, if the frame.size.height is set greater than 8192.0, the text just completely disappears.

I'm not sure what's special about that number, but when I set the frame with a height greater than that number, it stops working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView text becomes invisible after height reaches 8192.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582497/uitextview-text-becomes-invisible-after-height-reaches-8192-0)

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

> Note: In iOS 2.x, the maximum size of a UIView object is 1024 x 1024 points. In iOS 3.0 and later, views are no longer restricted to this maximum size but are still limited by the amount of memory they consume. It is in your best interests to keep view sizes as small as possible. Regardless of which version of iOS is running, you should consider tiling any content that is significantly larger than the dimensions the screen.

It seams that it is a memory problem and not a specific height

Comment: That does sound possible. So, how do I tile my content in the `UITextView`?

Comment: This Quotation was on UIView that is the superView of the UITextView ... So Tiling in UIView may be made with UITableView for example ... But I don't know in your case what you can do

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView

{

    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;

    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];

    CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;

    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);

    textView.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Comment: I'm already doing this. The problem is that, if `newsize.height` is greater than 8192.0, it stops working.

Comment: In the setting reduce the size & adjust code,the above code dynamically increases height

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
CGSize titlesize = [TxtValue.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(UITextView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

UITextView.frame=CGRectMake(TxtValue.frame.origin.x, TxtValue.frame.origin.y, TxtValue.frame.size.width, titlesize.height);
```

Comment: I'm already doing this. The problem is that, if `titlesize.height` is greater than 8192.0, it stops working.